# Salesforce popup on opportunity

Tags: popup, salesforce, apex, visualforce

For a client requirement in opportunity I have added a button to go to a visual force page. Before showing the next page though client wants to show a popup on that button click to confirm the operation. If not confirmed it should go to a different page. I am very new to salesforce. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using the Lightning version of Salesforce, you can follow the following steps:

- Create an **Aura Component** as follows:

**.cmp file**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
  Are you sure you want to proceed?
  <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
    <lightning:button
      label="No"
      variant="destructive"
      onclick="{!handleNo}"
    ></lightning:button>
    <lightning:button label="Yes" onclick="{!c.handleYes}"></lightning:button>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

**controller.js (replace MyOtherVisualforce and MyVisualforce with your Visualforce names)**

```
({
  handleNo: function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      url: "/apex/MyOtherVisualforce",
      isredirect: "true"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
  },

  handleYes: function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      url: "/apex/MyVisualforce",
      isredirect: "true"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
  }
});
```

- Create a new Action for the Opportunity object (go to the Buttons, Links and Actions section of the Opportunity setup and create new Action) and as Action Type select Lightning Component and as Lightning Component select the one that you just created
- Add the Action to your Opportunity layout

By doing this, the action will open your Aura Component which will present the two options that you need. After clicking one of the options, the e.force:navigateToURL will perform the redirection.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. I have created the said component but it is not showing in Lightning Component drop down. How to add the lightning component to the Action Type.

Comment: Error: No Lightning Component Quick Actions are available for your organization

Comment: Hi Hasan. Have you included the implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" in the first aura:component tag? It is really important for the Component to show in that picklist. If it is still not showing, the component is probably not deployed or saved in the org. Check your Developer Console to make sure that the component is there.

Comment: Thank you Oscar it worked. But I want to add this action to a button Like New Task. How can I add this action to a new task button?

Comment: What do you mean by a button like New Task? Do you mean as a Global Action? Could you update your answer with some screenshots with the desired behaviour?

Comment: I got it I added the action to the layout and its working thanks.

Comment: The popup is showing margin and padding around the popup. Any idea how can we remove that.

Comment: I think that margin can't be removed as it is being included by Salesforce when creating the popup for the quick action.

Comment: How can I add a init function. I want to check a condition and it yes do not want to show the popup and redirect to other page. Please help

Comment: You can check an example here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm

Comment: I checked it but it is not working for me. When I put the doInit function the buttons stop working. I put a question at stackoverflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791830/salesforce-lightning-component-init-function-call can you look at it please

Comment: I've answered your new question but you should do more debugging/checking prior to posting the questions. You will learn a lot also by doing so.